# Why doesent this repeat loop work as intended when the user first triggers the else statement and then answers yes?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, debugging, repeat

```py
def repeat():
    ques = input("Would you like to repeat the program? (yes or no): ").lower()

    if ques == "yes":
        return True

    elif ques == "no":
        exit()

    else:
        repeat()


bool = True
while bool:
    bool = repeat()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so...
The first thing you've done wrong is to use recursion to repeat the program:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion.

By default in python, a function returns 'None':

```py
>>> def f():
...     x = 0
... 
>>> print(f())
None
```

see https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/.

And in a whileloop `None` is considered as `False` as it is not `True`.

So when your function ends here after the execution of *repeat* :

```py
...
    else:
        repeat()
```

the function returns `None` value instead of `True`, and therefore the while loop ends.

You should instead use :

```
...
else:
    return repeat()
```

which will return what `repeat()` returns (True in case of the following answer "yes").

However I would have not done the program like this.

```
def repeat():
    r = True
    while r:
       ques = input(...).lower()
       if ques == "no":
           r = False
```

which avoids useless recursion issues.

Have a nice day :)